# Unable to get CImage to work in Visual C++ 2005 (MFC)

Tags: mfc, visual-c++-2005

I am using an example from MSDN, but I get "'CImage' : undeclared identifier"?

```
CImage myimage;
   // load existing image
   myimage.Load("image.bmp"); 
      // save an image in BMP format
   myimage.Save("c:\image1.bmp");
   // save an image in BMP format
   myimage.Save("c:\image2",ImageFormatBMP);
   // save an image in JPEG format
   myimage.Save("c:\image3.jpg");
   // save an image in BMP format, even though jpg file extension is used
   myimage.Save("c:\image4.jpg",ImageFormatBMP);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [documentation for `CImage`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bwea7by5%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) shows that it is defined in `atlimage.h`. You must `#include` that in your source. Also note the warning that you must include `afxstr.h` first to avoid errors.